# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'warn'

Tags: python, iphone, numpy, matplotlib, ipython

I wrote this code from this site https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/create-an-animated-gif-using-python-matplotlib/, but it gives this error for video = anim_created.to_html5_video ():
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'warn'

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from IPython import display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Figure = plt.figure()

lines_plotted = plt.plot([])

line_plotted = lines_plotted[0]

plt.xlim(0, 2 * np.pi)

plt.ylim(-1.1, 1.1)

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)

y = 0


def AnimationFunction(frame):
    y = np.cos(x + 2 * np.pi * frame / 100)
    line_plotted.set_data((x, y))


anim_created = FuncAnimation(Figure, AnimationFunction, frames=100, interval=25)
video = anim_created.to_html5_video()
html = display.HTML(video)
display.display(html)
plt.close()
```

Comment: It works fine on matplotlib 3.5.1, with no error being raised.

Comment: I have matplotlib 3.5.1, but it gives this error:   File "E:\my_venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 889, in __del__
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'warn'

Comment: Are you sure you run this **exact** code? Add the whole stacktrace. [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The issues originates from anim_created.to_html5_video() and is reproducible with matplotlib 3.5.1, Python 3.10.4, macOS 12.3.1

Comment: So, I have matplotlib 3.5.1، Python 3.10.4, Windows 11. I decided to use the code of this site https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-save-matplotlib-animation/ (Example 1), but I also got the error with the code: RuntimeError: Requested MovieWriter ( ffmpeg) not available